# strExtension - allow two formats

Tags: python

how is it possible to allow to formats for strExtension like .pdf and .html . 
If I change to strExtension = ".*" the script doesn´t work.
how can I use both formats ? pdf and html ?

```
# extension of files
strExtension = ".pdf" 
# for each file in source directory
for file in os.listdir(sourceDir):
    # if file ends with extension
if file.endswith(strExtension):
```

Comment: you can use `.endswith()` as you see in answer and in comment below answer. Or you can cut off extension and comare with tuple but without dot `if file.split(".")[-1] in ("pdf", "html"):` but it can fit also file with name `pdf` or `html`.

Comment: @furas that won't handle cases where a filename is `something.something_else.yet_another_thing.pdf` - so you'd have to either `.rsplit()` or better yet `.rpartition()` or `os.path.splitext()`...

Comment: @JonClements it handles it - maybe you see old comment when I forgot minus in `split(".")[-1]` but I agree that `os.path.splitext()` can be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.endswith()` does not support wildcards. It supports tuples however, so you can do:

```py
extensions = (".html", ".pdf")
if file.endswith(extensions):
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

Just test both cases:

```
if file.endswith(strExtension1) or file.endswith(strExtension2):
```

or as Jon Clements commented below:

```
if file.endswith((strExtension1,strExtension2)):
```

Comment: `str.endswith` accepts a tuple.... `if file.endswith((strExtension1, strExtension2))` for instance...

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for this remark, I didn't know it.

Comment: I Got:  if file.endswith(strExtension1, strExtension2):
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: @novregen did you put both extensions in () to form a tupel?

Comment: @novregen you get this TypeError when you forget when you write `endswith(strExtension1,strExtension2)` instead of `endswith((strExtension1,strExtension2))`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Thank you for the fast Help. Many Thanks at all of you...

```
# extension of files
strExtension1 = ".pdf"
strExtension2 = ".html" 
# for each file in source directory
for file in os.listdir(sourceDir):
# if file ends with extension
if file.endswith(strExtension1) or file.endswith(strExtension2):
```